# Equivalent of StreamReader.ReadToEnd() for C++ iostream

Tags: c++, iostream

Are there any simple way to read all text from a small text file into a std::string with C++ STL iostream?

I have tried something like

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
stringstream ss;

while(!f.eof()){
    array<char, READ_SIZE> buf;
    auto size = f.rdbuf()->sreadn(buf.data(), buf.size());
    if(size==0)break;
    ss<<string(buf.data(), size);
}

string str=ss.str();
```

Any better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
ostringstream ss;
ss << f.rdbuf();

string str = ss.str();
```